# Construct $\mathbb{Z}(X)$

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products, computer-algebra-systems

Is there any way to construct the ring $\mathbb{Z}(X)$ in a computer algebra system (e.g. MAGMA, Sage), where the parameter $X$ is adjoined to $\mathbb{Z}$.

(Note that this is **not** a field, so I cannot use the command for computing function field of the integral domain $\mathbb{Z}[X]$.)

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

Thanks to [henning-makholm](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/14366/henning-makholm) and [sharding4](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/254075/sharding4) for helping to ask correct question.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}\otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Q}(X)\cong \mathbb{Q}(X)$

Comment: If the thing you're looking for is not a field, then what _is_ it? How does it differ from the field of fractions of $\mathbb Z[X]$? (The elements of that fraction field is what a "rational function" usually means).

Comment: @sharding4, thanks! So silly of me!

Comment: @HenningMakholm, what I am actually looking at is adjoining of a parameter $X$ to $\mathbb{Z}$. Is it not same as rational functions over $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @HenningMakholm, I agree, the set of rational functions **will be** a field, as I can take $f(X)=1$ and $g(X)=2$, thus $\frac{f(X)}{g(X)}=\frac{1}{2}$ will be in this set and thus eventually we can prove that it will be a field!

But as I said above, I want adjoining of a parameter.

Comment: @user5325: I don't understand what you mean by "adjoining of a parameter", if you want that to produce something that is neither $\mathbb Z[X]$ nor the field of rational functions over $\mathbb Z$. Can you explain what the definition of the ring you want to get is, or give an example of an element of the ring that has no inverse?

Comment: e.g. the element $\frac{1}{X}$ will be in this ring, however the element $\frac{1}{2}$ will not be here. OK, Llet me speak from the commutative algebra point of view: 
This is the localization of the ring $\mathbb{Z}[Z]$ at the element $X$. I was thinking that computationally these two are the same!

Comment: @user5325 There is a package for Macaulay2 that allows you to do some things with local rings.

Comment: @FredrikMeyer, I know only one package in Macaulay2, namely [LocalRings](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2-1.9.2/share/doc/Macaulay2/LocalRings/html/). But this is for localization at **maximal** ideals. Is there any other package in Macaulay2? Any other CAS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know how to **remove** answer or mark it as non-answer (without deleting it)!

The $\mathbb{Z}(X)$ is localization of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, is absolutely correct. However the underlying multiplicative set is not $\{X,X^2,\ldots\}$, but $\mathbb{Z}$.

When you invert all non-costant polynomials, the ring you would get is $\mathbb{Z}(X)$ .

e.g. the element $\frac{1}{1+X}$ is in the ring and so is $\frac{1}{2+X}$, but $\frac{1}{2}$ is not there.

From computation point of view, I donno! Any pointers?

Hope this clarifies!

-- Mike

Answer (score 3):

The ring you are looking for is the Laurent Polynomial ring over $\mathbb{Z}$, namely $\mathbb{Z}[x,x^{-1}]$. This can be **constructed** as follows:
$$\frac{\mathbb{Z}[x][y]}{\langle xy-1\rangle}$$

This you can compute in almost all CASs.

Hope this helps.

-- Mike